# Simple Math with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I need a quick hand, I have this div below

`<div class="price">$1500</div>`

I need to do some simple math with that amount I need to divide it in half, then divide it by 6 and display the result like below.

`<span class="payment">Pay as low as $"result here" </span>`

I am a graphic designer I need this for a webpage and I know this should be simple but I just can't figure it out I really appreciate any help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this as below mentioned.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var price = $(".price").text(),
     price = price.replace('$', '');
     finalPrice = (price/2).toFixed(2);

$(".final-price").text(finalPrice/6);
  
 
    

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="price">$1500</div>
<br> <br>

<div class="payment">Pay as low as $<span class="final-price"></span> </div>
```

Comment: thank you very much i am getting very close with this is how i set it up `<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function($){
 var p = jQuery('.price').text(),
     p = p.replace('$', '');
     flexiPrice = (p/2).toFixed(2);

jQuery('.flex-price').text(flexiPrice/6);
  
});
</script>
<div style="clear:both; float:left; margin-bottom: 6px;" class="payment">Pay as low as $<span class="flex-price"></span>/month <a style="color:#3b5e3b; text-decoration:underline;" href="/financing">Learn More </a></div>` but i am getting $NaN my price looks like this $1,500.00

Comment: Please use this one..   
<script type="text/javascript"> 

 jQuery(document).ready(function($){
   var p = jQuery('.price').text(), 
       p = p.replace('$', '');
       flexiPrice = (p/2).toFixed(2);

    jQuery('.flex-price').text(flexiPrice/6); }); 

    </script>

    <div class="price">$1500</div>

    <div style="clear:both; float:left; margin-bottom: 6px;" class="payment">Pay as low as $<span class="flex-price"></span>/month 


         <a style="color:#3b5e3b; text-decoration:underline;" href="/financing">Learn More </a>

    </div>

Comment: that is not working my price looks like this `<div class="price">$1,500.00</div>` how do i remove the " , " in the price looks like that's what's breaking it

Comment: <script type="text/javascript"> 
 jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var p = jQuery('.price').text(), 
         p = p.replace('$', ''),
         abc = p.replace(',', ''),
         flexiPrice = (abc/2).toFixed(2);
 jQuery('.flex-price').text((flexiPrice/6).toFixed(2)); }); 
</script>
    <div class="price">$1,500.00</div>
    <div style="clear:both; float:left; margin-bottom: 6px;" class="payment">Pay as low as $<span class="flex-price"></span>/month 
         <a style="color:#3b5e3b; text-decoration:underline;" href="/financing">Learn More </a>
    </div>

Comment: jQuery(document).ready(function($){
 var p = jQuery('.price').text(),
     p = p.replace('$', '');
     p = p.replace(',', '');
     flexiPrice = (p/2).toFixed();

jQuery('.flex-price').text(flexiPrice/6).toFixed();

Comment: above is working but it producing a long number $1,510 is resulting to $125.83333333333333

Comment: Have you used ".toFixed(2)" to the final price?   
 jQuery('.flex-price').text((flexiPrice/6).toFixed(2));    It will produce the result e.g.... $9279.50

Answer (score 2):

First get text of div `var text = $('.price').text(); // "$1500"`
Then parse it as integer `var price = text.replace(/[^\d]/, ''); // "$1500" -> 1500`
Finally place text to where it belongs: `$('.payment').text('Pay as low as $'+(price / 2 / 6));`

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var text = $('.price').text();
  var price = text.replace(/[^\d]/, '');
  $('.payment span').text(price / 12);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="price">$1500</div>
<span class="payment">Pay as low as $<span></span> </span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, this one is pure javascript, try not to overcomplicate things

```html
<html>
<body>

    <div id="num">1500$</div>
    <div id="num2"></div>

    <script>
        var number = document.getElementById("num").innerHTML.replace("$", "");
        number = number / (2 * 6);
        document.getElementById("num2").innerHTML = "Pay as low as " + number + " here";
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

> 1. get the `text()` of the element.
> 2. replace the `$` sign
> 3. And divide by `(2*6)`
> 4. Apply with some `Math.abs` function its will calculate the result
> 5. Then apply the `span` and append into your body

```js
var a = Math.abs(parseInt($('.price').text().replace('$',''))/(2*6))

$('body').append('<span class="payment">Pay as low as $'+a+' </span>')
```

```css
.payment{
color:green;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="price">$1500</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var price = parseInt( $( ".price" ).html().replace(/\D/g, "") );
$( ".payment" ).html( "Pay as low as " + (price/12) );
```

**Demo**

```js
  var price = parseInt( $( ".price" ).html().replace(/\D/g, "") );
    $( ".payment" ).html( "Pay as low as " + (price/12) );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="price">$1500</div>
<span class="payment">Pay as low as $"result here" </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you should do:

1. Get the `.price` div's text.
2. convert it to an `int`.
3. Now you should divide it with `(value/2)/6`
4. Put the value in the desired target element.

```js
var price = +$('.price').text().slice(1);
var pay = (price/2)/6
$('p').text("Pay as low as $"+pay);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="price">$1500</div>
<p></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

hope it help.

```js
 /*define a function to Deleting all characters other than numbers. in element*/
  function checkIsInteger(sTr){
  var newstr = "";
  if(typeof sTr !== "undefine" && sTr!=""){
   var indexInt = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'];
   for(var i=0;i<sTr.length;i++){
    var cek = sTr.substr(i,1)
    if(indexInt.indexOf(cek)>=0){
     newstr += sTr.substr(i,1);
    }
   }
  }
  return newstr;
 }

$("#res").html((parseInt(checkIsInteger($("#price").html()))/2)/6);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="price" id="price">$1500</div>
<label class="payment" id="pym">Pay as low as $<span id="res">result</span> here </label>
```